# What's wrong with this mySQL query? (concat and cast)

Tags: mysql

The following mySQL query always returns 0 results. The problem began when I added the part that uses the concat and the cast functions. Can you see any syntax error in it?

```
SELECT p.seccio_id as seccio, 
       count(distinct r.usuari_upc) as usuaris, 
       sum(r.preu) as preu
FROM report r, persona p 
WHERE r.usuari_upc = p.persona_id  
       and ((r.any = 2017 and r.mes = 1) 
            or (r.any > 2017 and r.any < 2018) 
            or (r.any = 2018 and r.mes = 1) 
            or (2017 != 2018  
                and ((r.any = 2017 and r.mes > 1)  
                or (r.any = 2018 and r.mes < 1))))  
       and (p.any_id = '2017-2018' 
           or p.any_id = '2016-2017') 
       /* The problem is here. */
       and ((r.mes < 9 
            and p.any_id = CONCAT(CAST(r.any - 1 as varchar(4)),"-",CAST(r.any as varchar(4)))) 
            or (r.mes >= 9 and p.any_id = CONCAT(CAST(r.any as varchar(4)),"-",CAST(r.any + 1 as varchar(4))))) 
GROUP BY p.seccio_id 
ORDER BY p.seccio_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast straight from the numeric values to varchar(4) - if you change them all to char(4), you lose the syntax errors.